# Using Material-ui for creating an inline form with label,text, select and button elements (similar to Boostrap)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to create an inline form using `Material-UI` and `React` which resembles the following

[image]

### Bootstrap HTML snippet

I created the above using the HTML snippet below. You can try this out at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h).

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Inline form</h2>
  <p>Make the viewport larger than 768px wide to see that all of the form elements are inline, left aligned, and the labels are alongside.</p>
  <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select search field:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>FirstName</option>
        <option>LastName</option>
        <option>PostCode</option>
        <option>Gender</option>
      </select>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter search pattern" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

### My attempt using Material-ui

[image]

```
                <label htmlFor="selectsearchfield">Select search fields</label>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <NativeSelect id="selectsearchfield" value={{}}>
                    <option value="FirstName">FirstName</option>
                    <option value="LastName">LastName</option>
                </NativeSelect>

                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <TextField
                        label=""  id="outlined-size-small" defaultValue="" variant="outlined" size="small" disableUnderline />
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <Button size="medium" variant="contained" color="primary">Search</Button>
```

### Question

It can be clearly seen that the output from Bootstrap is far more professional.
Please, any suggestions on how to improve the inline form using Material UI look n feel so that it comes close to Bootstrap.

Thank you,

Sau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `material-ui` `makeStyles` and make it **responsive** also:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  Button,
  FormControl,
  OutlinedInput,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Select,
  MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "PostCode", "Gender"];
  const [searcBy, setSearchBy] = useState("FirstName");
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <form className={classes.form}>
        <FormControl className={classNames(classes.formControl, classes.text)}>
          <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.type}>
            Select search fields:
          </Typography>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl
          className={classNames(classes.formControl, classes.select)}
        >
          <Select
            labelId="typesLabel"
            label="Types"
            input={<OutlinedInput classes={{ input: classes.input }} />}
            value={searcBy}
            onChange={e => setSearchBy(e.target.value)}
          >
            {fields.map(field => (
              <MenuItem key={field} value={field}>
                {field}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl
          className={classNames(classes.formControl, classes.search)}
        >
          <TextField
            label="Enter search pattern"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            value={searchText}
            onChange={e => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.submitBtn}
        >
          Primary
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  form: {
    width: 800,
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    minWidth: 120
  },
  type: {
    fontWeight: 600
  },
  formControl: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      minWidth: "100%",
      marginRight: theme.spacing(0),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  input: {
    padding: "10px 14px"
  },
  select: {
    maxWidth: 130
  },
  search: {
    maxWidth: 180
  },
  submitBtn: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      width: "100%"
    }
  }
}));
```

Or you can also incorporate the use of `Grid` from `@material-ui/core.Grid` instead of using 'flex' like the above example.

Here is the result:-

[image]

- a bit of explanation of what happened above:-

  - having `input={<OutlinedInput classes={{ input: classes.input }} />}` as `select` element `props` will enable us to create our own `outline` instead of depending on the given example code from **[material-ui select](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)** documentation code.
  - the reason why we do this is since you want to make it exactly as you did with `Bootstraps` example above. We need to somehow make the `select` element tad shorter in height. With element `TextField`, you can just specify `size="small"`. But for `select`, that option is not available. That's why we have this approach. Or you can directly change the `select` input element overall styles with `withStyles` of `material-ui/core/styles`.

You can also refer to this [sandbox code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkqpsu?file=src%2FApp.js) to see the actual working result.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Before, I give you the points , please could you also explain - how were you able to render the top border of the SELECT element?

Comment: actually you can find/copy it directly from the [materiall-ui-select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#select) documentation itself. Under `Simple Select`

Comment: I already update the code above with explanations. Hope it helps